# How to take the datas from firebase in order?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing chat app, the problem is I can not take the datas from firebase, on the chat screen nothing shown as a chat, To sort my datas on firebase to take them to my chat screen like a real chat app, I used  orderBy('createAt', descending: true).snapshots() property, It sort my datas on firebase according time, but before I used this parameter I could see the messages but now I can, Thanks for your answers, Have a nice day..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:naber/constants.dart';

final _firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id="chat_screen";
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser()async{
    try{
      final currentUser =  await _auth.currentUser;
      if(currentUser!=null){
        loggedInUser=currentUser;
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').
      orderBy('createAt', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data()['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe});

  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
        isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))
                : BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
[![Here is my database screenshot][1]][1]
```

Comment: Why is 'User loggedInUser' outside of your class? I would declare it in the scope of your _ChatScreenState, and in getCurrentUser(), wrap the 'loggedInUser=currentUser' in a setState() to rebuild your Widget. (getCurrentUser() is async, so it might finish AFTER your build() method finishes the first time.

Comment: Because I used loggedInUser ın other class which is make speech bubble

Comment: The stream may get terminated with error.. few queries with orderby needs indexing. If it's not in your database already it will terminate with an error.. check for stream error state `snapshot.state == ConnectionState.error` to debug more..